# Extended Page Tables / Nested Paging : prevention of traps on a guest PTE update

Tags: memory-management, virtualization, page-tables

So I studied about EPTs in Intel's Virtualization Extensions. I understand that with shadow page tables, the VMM has to write-protect the hardware-accessible shadow PT so that whenever a guest attempts to write to the PT, it traps to the VMM. This software-based page table management is a huge overhead that is supposed to be solved by EPTs / Nested Paging.

But how does nested paging solve this problem? In this case, we have 2 separate translations: Guest VA to Guest PA (which is host VA), and Host VA to Host (Machine) PA. It is claimed that guest updates to the guest-managed page table need not trap. This is incoherent: If the guest changes the GVA->GPA mapping, shouldn't the new GPA mapping also be reflected in the HVA? In other words, shouldn't every change in the guest-managed page table also be reflected in the VMM managed page table? We seem to have the same problem. What problem does the introduction of EPTs solve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to figure this one out for my take-home exam. Turns out it's really a very small detail: When a new VM is instantiated, the page table pointed to by the Host CR3 pointer is loaded with an entire set of Guest Physical ->  Host Physical address mappings; i.e, since these mappings are stationary / static, there would be no need to update them on the fly when the VMs are running.

Answer (score 1):

> i.e, since these mappings are stationary / static, there would be no need to update them on the fly when the VMs are running.

Not sure about it but: it could happen EPT mapping (from GPA -> HPA) does not exist for a GP page. In that case an EPT violation/misconfiguration VM exit will be triggered and handled by VMM. It is in charge of VMM to allocate the host physical page and setup the associated EPT entry for the mapping